# Add class to group specific div on focus with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, onblur, onfocus, dom-traversal

In the following code, I'm trying to make it so that when an input is selected (focused), that the `formhead` div in the associated fieldset changes its background color, and on blur it changes back.  I would like to do this by adding a class to that same div on focus, and having that class removed on blur.  jQuery closest is the most similar in concept to what I'm trying to do, but isn't appropriate because it will only target parent divs.  Is there something else that would target the nearest div with that class, without affecting the other classes in the other fieldsets?  Or do I have to get much more specific and id the formheads, etc?

```
<fieldset>
<div class="formhead">Heading Title 1</div>
<div class="fieldleft">
    <label for="specificinput">Input Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="forminput" id="specificinput">
</div>
<div class="fieldleft">
    <label for="specificinput">Input Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="forminput" id="specificinput">
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<div class="formhead">Heading Title 2</div>
<div class="fieldleft">
    <label for="specificinput">Input Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="forminput" id="specificinput">
</div>
<div class="fieldleft">
    <label for="specificinput">Input Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="forminput" id="specificinput">
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

And the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').focus(function( ){
    $(this).closest('.formhead').addClass('bluebg');
  });
    $('input').focus(function( ){
    $(this).closest('.formhead').removeClass('bluebg');
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the input's `.formhead` with this line:

```
$(this).closest('fieldset').find('.formhead').addClass('bluebg');
```

You can also write this as (actually the same, using context):

```
$('.formhead', $(this).closest('fieldset')).addClass('bluebg');
```

The easiest way I see for your code would be something like:

```
$('input.forminput').bind('focus blur', function () {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.formhead').toggleClass('bluebg');
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zj4dm/)

This will assign the same handler for `onfocus` and `onblur`, which will just toggle the class of `.formhead`.

- [Multiple events with `.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#multiple-events)
- [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: Thanks, just what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can also match the parent `<div>` element with class `fieldleft` using [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), then proceed to its `formhead` sibling using [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:text").bind("focus blur", function() {
        $(this).closest(".fieldleft").prevAll(".formhead").toggleClass("bluebg");
    });
});
```

Comment: This only seems to work on the input field just following the formhead div.  Any inputs below that are unable to target it, probably due to limitations of prev

Comment: @hisnameisjimmy, you're absolutely right, `prevAll()` must be used here. Answer updated accordingly, thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score -1):

you can use [**.next()**](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: How would `.next()` help here?